# How to indicate a port number in a unix command (SCP) when copying files from a one remote server to another?

Tags: unix, scp, port-number

I have a case when there are 2 remote hosts, each with a unique port number, which i both need to indicate when using SCP command. There is no problem indicating the unique (non 22) port number for the first one, but i can't figure out how to indicate it for the second one.

Here is how it looks like now -

```
scp -P 1234 username@site.com:/path/to/file username2@site2.com:/path/to/directory
```

Comment: `scp ... site1:file -o Port=2345 site2...` I don't have a way to test this for your case. Good luck.

Comment: not accepting -o argument, nor port specification...

Answer (score 1):

The way that you are running scp in your question, it would just invoke the scp program on the first host, telling it to send the file to the second host. You can directly invoke `ssh` to run the scp command on the first host however you like it:

```
ssh -p1234 user1@host1 'scp -P2345 /path/to/file user2@host2:/path/to/directory'
```

If the first host can't connect directly to the second host, you'd normally use the scp option `-3` to send the data from the first host to the second host through you local host. If you're in that position, you could emulate how scp runs that kind of transfer, though it's sort of a hack:

```
yes "" | tr '\n' '\0' |
    ssh -p1234 user1@host1 'scp -f /path/to/file' |
    ssh -p2345 user2@host2 'scp -t /path/to/directory'
```

This is based on [how the SCP protocol works](https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works). The first `ssh` line runs scp on the first remote host in "remote source" mode to send the source file. The second `ssh` lines runs scp on the second host in "remote sink" mode to receive the file and write it to the directory. "remote source" and "remote sink" are what `scp` normally runs on the remote system when receiving or sending files, respectively.

The `yes "" | tr '\n' '\0' |` line creates a stream of NUL (Ascii 0) bytes which are needed for the protocol to work. The `scp -f` instance reads these and won't send files without them. There are other ways to generate a stream of NUL bytes if you like.

Comment: I think, there is also a problem with SSH keys. It seems, they are not getting read correctly. I am entering passphrases, they are not accepted, and then i am getting lead to enter password, and it doesn't get accepted either. This is for the second option that you offer in your answer. When i SSH separately into both accounts i have no problems with passphrases and reading SSH keyfiles. It is confusing.

Comment: Yes, with the second example, it'll be almost impossible to enter passwords or passphrases for both ssh instances. You can only bend the command-line utilities so far.

Comment: "Cannot fork into background without a command to execute."

Answer (score -1):

no idea how to do this with arguments, but you can try editing  ~/.ssh/config

```
Host test
  HostName test.com
  Port 22000
  User me
```

Comment: i would like to avoid that, if possible. Just one line, all in the same command would be great.